# How to access an entry from a void pointer?

Tags: c

I want to cast this as a pointer to be able to access the third entry from it. so I used sscanf to convert the string into hex pointer.

The problem is whenever I do `s_c_t_addr[2]`, I get an error "invalid use of void expression". Any hints on what might be the cause of this problem? should I change the type from `void*`? if yes, what should be the new type?

I am still a beginner, so go easy on me

Comment: You should include the rest of the code, where you define and obtain everything you are using in this block... otherwise it's not a [mre].

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Yeah sure I can do that. I just didn't want to spam the question. I will update it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct type for `sys_call_table` depends on the architecture. On x86 is `sys_call_ptr_t *`, since it's an array of function pointers, on ARM64 it's `syscall_fn_t **`. You can declare it like this:

```c
sys_call_ptr_t *sys_call_table;
```

In any case, it should be fine even if declared as `void **`:

```c
void **sys_call_table;
```

Then, since you are writing a kernel module, there's no need to complicate your life by reading and parsing the contents of `System.map`, you can use [`kallsym_lookup_name()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.11/source/kernel/kallsyms.c#L165) (including `linux/kallsym.h`). This will also work with KASLR enabled.

```c
sys_call_table = (sys_call_ptr_t)kallsyms_lookup_name("sys_call_table");
```

In your case, it should be:

```c
sys_call_ptr_t *sys_call_table;
char *sys_call_table_addr;
unsigned long ul;

// ...

sscanf(sys_call_table_addr, "%lx", &ul);
sys_call_table = (sys_call_ptr_t *)ul;
```

Finally, you can obtain the address of `fork` just like you are doing, but on the right variable (not `char *`), and remember that it is a pointer, and therefore the correct format specifier is `%px` if you want to print the *real* address (or `%p` if you want to print a hashed address, see [this documentation page](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.17/core-api/printk-formats.html#pointer-types) for more details).

```c
printk(KERN_INFO "fork address: %px\n", sys_call_table[__NR_fork]);
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. I am totally with you that I shouldn't do it by reading system.map, but I was required by my professor to do it this way.

Comment: @MinaAshraf updated the answer as I had the wrong type name. You can also use `void **`, the correct type to use depends on the architecture.

Comment: so if I changed the type of sys_call_table as you suggested, would this work the way I am trying to do? or it only works with the kallsyms_lookup_name ?

Comment: @MinaAshraf oh yeah it works, no problem with that. I did not check if *all* the parsing is correct, but doing `sscanf(sys_call_table_address, "%lx", &ul)` and then casting to `sys_call_ptr_t` is OK.

Comment: I did it this way but I am still getting an error. the error says: subscripted value is pointer to function

Comment: @MinaAshraf you missed a `*`, it should be `sys_call_ptr_t *sys_call_table_addr`, as I show in my answer above.

Comment: yes, sorry about that. did you also mean I should cast it into (sys_call_ptr_t *) or (sys_call_ptr_t) because that was what confused me when you said "and then casting to sys_call_ptr_t"

Comment: @MinaAshraf added a snippet to my answer to make it clear.